# Alter text() while preserving children of element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Considering the following example:

```
<root>
 <a>foo
  <b>bar</b>
 </a>
</root>
```

How can I change the text() of `<a>` to "fee" while preserving the child element `<b>` with all its children, attributes, etc.?

Using `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`, only the text() is processed, correct? Using `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, I cannot alter the text(), e.g. via `replace` function. So how can I change both. Note that my actual use case is more complex, with multiple children and the text() not necessarily in the first position.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define templates which match text nodes, not just elements. You could make a template which matches text nodes which are children of `a` elements, e.g.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="a/text()">
     <xsl:value-of select="replace(., 'foo', 'fee')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```xml
<root>
 <a>fee
  <b>bar</b>
 </a>
</root>
```

By the way, you don't mention what version of XSLT you're running though you mention the `replace` function which implies you're version 2 or later. That stylesheet is version 3.0 but the only thing not supported in XSLT 2 is the `mode` element which is effectively just an identity template.

To answer your question about `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`; what happens is that `xsl:value-of` converts the current node (`.`) to a string. If the current node is an element (like your `a` element), then its text value is the result of concatenating *all* its descendant text nodes, not just the child text nodes; i.e. it equals `string-join(.//text())`, and *not* `string-join(./text())`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this XSLT-1.0 template in combination with the identity template:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />fee
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::text()[1])]" />  
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This should replace the first `text()` node of the `<a>` element.

Comment: This will error out if `a` has any attributes. If you want to assume that it never will, then do not apply templates to them.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Splitted the `apply-templates` accordingly.